# printf() - Insufficient arguments error

Tags: string, vim, count, printf

I'm trying to read an input from a inputdialog and put them in a printf() command.

p.e.
inputdialog variable:

```
b = "this is my number list %d and %02f"
```

1)
First I don't know how many "%" items there are in "b".
I want to count them by counting all characters and removing all "%" items and count the difference (= nr. of "%" items):

```
   let totlength = strlen(b) 
   let tempsubst = strlen(substitute(b, '%\ze\S', "","g"))
   let NrPercentages = totlengte - tempsubst
```

I can't find out what is the right regex to substitute all characters which aren't '%\ze\S' (the negative way)
Can anyone help me?

2)
If I know the number of "%" items from the inputdialog field I can create my printf() for a certain range "i"

```
   let nrOfi = 'i'
   if NrPercentages > 0
     let nrOfi = nrOfi.repeat(',i', NrPercentages-1)
   endif

   for i in range(1,10,2) 
       put=printf(''.b.'',eval(nrOfi))
   endfor
```

This gives an error.. Insufficient arguments for printf()
   What did I wrong?

Comment: @Ingo, what's wrong with this question? :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first point, you're looking for this:

```
  let tempsubst = strlen(substitute(b, '[^%]', "","g"))
```

Comment: Thank you odessos, but it is not the single % I want to find but values like these: `%02d, %d, %3d, %e, %E, %g, %G, %.2e, %.2f`, (or values with a Non Space character after the `%`)